# TensorFlow "Received a mix of batched and unbatched Tensors, or Tensors are not compatible with Specs"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement DQN on a custom environment with TensorFlow.
I've finished implementing the environment class and integrate it as a part of the DQN environment.
However, I got an error,

> Received a mix of batched and unbatched Tensors, or Tensors are not compatible with Specs.  num_outer_dims: 1.
> Saw tensor_shapes:
> TimeStep(step_type=TensorShape([1]), reward=TensorShape([1]), discount=TensorShape([1]), observation=TensorShape([1, 1, 6]))
> And spec_shapes:
> TimeStep(step_type=TensorShape([]), reward=TensorShape([]), discount=TensorShape([]), observation=TensorShape([6]))

I found the same error in the issues of Tensorflow, but I couldn't find the exact solution.
In the environment class I defined, I specified the action spec and observation spec as,

```
    self._action_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
        shape=(), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=nq, name='action')
    self._observation_spec = array_spec.BoundedArraySpec(
        shape=(nq,), dtype=np.int32, minimum=0, maximum=1, name='observation')
```

where *nq* is an integer value. I don't know why the TensorShapes look like those.

Thank you.

Comment: Interesting I encountered this problem while implementing PPO in TF-Agents I wonder if there is a connection to the fact that we are both implementing RL-Agents of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, and what I was doing wrong was that in my custom environment I was not returning the state with the correct shape, I was inserting it into an array

```
return np.array([self.state], dtype=np.float64)
```

instead of

```
return np.array(self.state, dtype=np.float64)
```

This was the reason why the tensor shapes weren't adding up. I don't know if it would solve your problem, but it might help someone else

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same error. I don’t know exactly what solved it but one problem was with the notebook (ipynb) – you have to wait some time for the chapters to compute and maybe click again after some time, maybe try your code in a py-file without notebook.
Another thing I changed is the definition of the observation space in my gym-env from spaces.Discrete to spaces.Box, e.g.:

```
self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=2000, shape=(20, 20), dtype=np.int32)
```